# Parsing HTML with Nokogiri not all tags are present

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri

There is this dictionary: [Russian dictionary](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=110&sc=4&recno=3506179&dict=&l1=1&l2=2)

In ruby I am trying to get the url of the next page - ">>" which is

```
<a href="m.exe?a=110&sc=4&recno=3506774&dict=&l1=1&l2=2">>></a>
```

When inspecting this element in browser, it is there and it is present. However, using

```
link = "http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=110&sc=4&recno=3506179&dict=&l1=1&l2=2"
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link))
puts "#{page}"
```

The link to the next page is not printed. All the links to alphabet letters are there, but the there is no

```
<a href="m.exe?a=110&sc=4&recno=3506774&dict=&l1=1&l2=2">>></a>
```

Is this somehow dynamically generated and ruby doesn't catch it(?)
The links of the "next pages" don't have any logical sequence, so I can't increment the url itself..
Any help appriciated

Comment: You can see the '>>' link in the source with js off - so it is not generated client side - that's not the problem.

Comment: Also, the >> are not encoded in the source as &gt;&gt; Maybe that is tripping up the Nokogiri parser

Comment: For what it's worth, I just ran your code and it's skipping the >> on my machine as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original guess was right. The page only includes the next link for specific user agents.

Try pretending to be Google Chrome like this:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link, 'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'))
```